# Native password mask symbol in Java

Tags: java

Ho to get system native password mask symbol in Java?
It can be star in old Windows, big circle in new Windows, some other symbol in Linux and mac.

Update: swing solution is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWT:

```
  TextField password = new TextField(8);
  password.getEchoChar();
```

In Swing:

```
 JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField();
 jpf.getEchoChar();
```

In the console, it is a bit tricky to set (check http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask/). To get, maybe playing with `Console.writer()`.

Anyway, why on earth would you want to get that echo char?

Comment: I need edit password inside table. Now I try SWT, any ideas how to get this symbol there?

Comment: Ok, i found the solution for SWT. Text class has method getEchoChar that returns what i needed.